# 23502: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework

I create a table with primary key.

I tried to insert new data with entityframework6, but it would get 23502 error.

But I add the default value to the column before I insert it.

I don't understand why it would get this error.

Table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE ERRORLOG(
id numeric NOT NULL,
message varchar(50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT pterrorlog_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Model:

```
public partial class ERRORLOG
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public long ID { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
    public string MESSAGE { get; set; }
}
```

Funcation:

```
using (DbContext Db as new DbContext)
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    ERRORLOG iLog = new ERRORLOG();
    iLog.MESSAGE = Message;
    Db.ERRORLOG.Add(iLog);
    Db.SaveChanges(); //Get 23502 error
}
```

Here is the insert script, it looks like didn't insert the id, why is that?

```
INSERT INTO "pterrorlog"("message") VALUES (@p_0) RETURNING "id"
```

Edit:

After I add this script on the Model, it works fine now.

```
public partial class ERRORLOG
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
  public long ID { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
  public string MESSAGE { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The error msg is clear. You are trying to insert `NULL` to non null column `id`.Show your insert statement as well.

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy I update the statement, it looks like it didn't insert the id column, why is that?

Comment: I could see you are not passing any values to `id`. Is it an auto increment column?

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy I use this script to set its value : public long ID { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Entity Framework auto insert a value to the column.
After I add the script to prevent this issue, it works fine now.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

Model would like:

```
public partial class ERRORLOG
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
  public long ID { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
  public string MESSAGE { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PGAdmin to profile the SQL that EF is actually attempting to execute on `SaveChanges`. C# is case sensitive while Postgres defaults to lower case. If I recall NPGSQL will format all EF SQL Queries with double-quotes so if your Entities were declared with properties like ID, it would be generating statements like `INSERT INTO "ERRORLOG" ( "ID", "MESSAGE" ) VALUES ( ... )` so a column named "id" wouldn't be getting set.

If you want your entities to use a different case than the DB, and leave Postgres using lower case then I'd recommend using `[Column]` attributes to rename the columns:

```
public partial class ERRORLOG
{
    [Key, Column(Name = "id")]
    public long ID { get; set; } = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
    [Column(Name = "message")]
    public string MESSAGE { get; set; }
}
```

The other detail is that `Order` on the `Column` attribute is only needed when dealing with composite keys, such as many-to-many joining tables where the PK is made up of two or more columns. It isn't needed for normal single-value PKs.

If that isn't the cause, checking the insert statement in PGAdmin should give you a clue what NPGSQL / EF is attempting to execute.